# Want to connect Sony Z2 (Android phone) to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb, android, sony

I have **Ubuntu 12.04** and I try to connect it with **Sony Xperia Z2** (which has Android 4.4) via USB.

I have set **Mass Storage Mode(MSC)** setting but nothing happens when I connect cell phone to the laptop.

Comment: You should try update the MTS support (which is bad on 12.04). Try add the PPA described on this article: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html

Comment: I have done all steps from this article (except reverting changes) but my phone is still not found.

Answer (score 0):

The internal "sdcard" memory of this phone will only be exposed to Ubuntu after we had allowed **USB debug mode**. To do so we need to activate the developer's tool menu by 7 taps on the about phone build number entry.

After that the phone's internal sdcard can be mounted with read and write permissions  as a mass storage device without further tweaks using Nautilus. Only after allowing USB-debugging we will also have ADB-access from the command line.

> This inconvenience was introduce to protect the phone's internal file system from accidental damage. Therefore be cautious about data you are going to write to the phone's internal memory.

Comment: Still nothing was mounted...

Answer (score 0):

Mount using this script: This has been tested on Sony Xperia Z2 (Ubuntu 12.04 - 14.04)

https://github.com/eagleEye0101/mount_android_ubuntu.git

Comment: What does this script do? How does it work? Are there ways to do it without said script? Is the script even necessary? It's one command.

Comment: yes it is single command ... but you (beginners) do not have to remember the command each time. They can just use the script with mount or unmount option. You can see the command uses MTP servise to mount android phone. Because by default ubuntu does not mount some android devices (example: Sony Xperia Z2).